# How to get data to DropDownList based on other dropdown?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a table `(dept)` on database and fields are:

```
1 - id
2 - Division
3 - Designation
```

I am retrieving `division` data on dropdown, this is my code:

```
public JsonResult GetDivision()
    {
        var division = db.Depts.GroupBy(x => x.Division)
                       .Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault()).OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
        return Json(division);
    }
```

Now I want to get the designation data on 2nd dropdown based on division name

```
 public JsonResult GetDesignation(int StateId)
     {
         var department = db.Depts.Where(x => x.DeptId == StateId)
                          .OrderBy(x => x.Designation);
         return Json(department);
     }
```

Ajax code:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
             $('#division').change(function () {
                 $('#designation').empty();
                 $.ajax({
                     type: "POST",
                     url: "/Official/GetDesignation",
                     datatype: "Json",
                     data: { StateId: $('#division').val() },
                     success: function (data) {
                         $('#designation').append('<option value>--Select--</option>');
                         $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                                $('#designation').append('<option value="' + value.deptId + '">' + value.designation + '</option>');
                                            console.log(value);
                                });
                      }
               });
           });
```

html:

```
  @Html.DropDownList("division", new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "--Select--", null)
  @Html.DropDownList("designation", new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "--Select--", null)
```

When I select divison from dropdown, I get only one designation, which is getting from id, but I want to get all designation based on division name for exmaple I have this type of data

```
id division               designation
1  CORPORATE AFFAIRS      Manager Corporate Affairs 
2  CORPORATE AFFAIRS      Manager BPR & PMO
3  CORPORATE AFFAIRS      Jr. Executive Corporate Governance
```

in 1st dropdown I am getting one "corporate affairs", but when I select "corporate affairs" I need to get all designation in 2nd dropdown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think you need to understand the following...

This line here:

```
   var department = db.Depts.Where(x => x.DeptId == StateId)                            
                   .OrderBy(x => x.Designation);
```

Is making a SQL query at the end, which will traduce into something like:

```
   SELECT * FROM Depts WHERE DeptId = Something ORDER BY Designation
```

I assume that DeptId is a PRIMARY KEY, which is a unique value on the table, when you process the query above it will bring only one or zero results depending on if there is a match.

I think you should correct the value that you are passing from the ajax POST, you could use:

```
data: { StateId: $('#division').text() }
```

instead of:

```
data: { StateId: $('#division').val() }
```

This way you are passing the Division name as string and modify your function as follows:

```
 public JsonResult GetDesignation(string Division)
 {
     var department = db.Depts.Where(x => x.Division == Division)
                      .OrderBy(x => x.Designation);
     return Json(department);
 }
```

Comment: its still not working, i did exact as you said but i am getting nothing in 2nd dropdown.....

Comment: I think we need to know two things: first, can you post the html generated from the division select? Second, can you post the data returned on your ajax request?

Comment: its worked ! thanks need to ask another thing can you check this  
public JsonResult GetDesignation(string Division)
 {
     var department = db.Depts.Where(x => x.Division == Division)
                      .OrderBy(x => x.Designation);
     return Json(department); }
now i am getting designation based on division but i have some designation with the same name, how i can remove duplicate one?

Comment: JsonResult GetDesignation(string Division) { var department = db.Depts.Where(x => x.Division == Division) .GroupBy(x => x.Designation).Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault()).OrderBy(x => x.Designation).ToList(); return Json(department); }